# what is the file ORA_DUMMY_FILE.f in oracle?

Tags: oracle, parallel-processing, oracle12c, file-descriptor

oracle version: 12.2.0.1

As you know, these are then unix processes for the  parallel servers in oracle:

```
ora_p000_ora12c
ora_p001_ora12c
....
ora_p???_ora12c
```

They can be seen also with the view: gv$px_process.
The spid for each parallel server can be obtained from there.

Then  I look for the open files associated with te parallel server here:

```
ls -l /proc/<spid>/fd
```

And I'm obtaining around 500-10000 file descriptors  for several parallel servers equal to this one:

```
991 -> /u01/app/oracle/admin/ora12c/dpdump/676185682F2D4EA0E0530100007FFF5E/ORA_DUMMY_FILE.f (deleted)
```

I've deleted them using:(actually I've create a small script for doing it because there are thousands of them)

```
gdb -p <spid>
    gdb> p close(<fd_id>)
```

But after some hours the file descriptors start being created again (hundreds every day)

If they are not deleted then eventually the linux limit is reached and any parallel query throws an error like this:

```
ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P001
ORA-01116: error in opening database file 132
ORA-01110: data file 132: '/u02/oradata/ora12c/pdbname/tablespacenaname_ts_1.dbf'
ORA-27077: too many files open
```

Does anyone have any idea of how and why this file descriptors are being created, and how to avoid it?.

**Edited: *Added some more information that could be useful***.
I've tested that when a new PDB is created a directory DATA_PUMP_DIR is created in it (select * from all_directories) that is pointing to:

```
/u01/app/oracle/admin/ora12c/dpdump/<xxxxxxxxxxxxx>
```

The linux directory is also created.
Also one file descriptor is created pointing to ORA_DUMMY_FILE.f in the new dpdump subdirectory like the ones described initially

```
lsof | grep "ORA_DUMMY_FILE.f (deleted)"

/u01/app/oracle/admin/ora12c/dpdump/<xxxxxxxxxxxxx>/ORA_DUMMY_FILE.f (deleted)
```

This may be ok, the problem I face is the continuos growing of the file descriptors pointing to ORA_DUMMY_FILE that reach the linux limits.

Comment: Never, ever, EVER do that, unless you don't care about your data. Increase your max open files limit. Or open an SR if you think something is "leaking".

Comment: well, it is a developing DB. There is not real data there. But it is important to have it up and working. Anyway I'm afraid that this could happen in the environment where we have data, so I want to understand what is happening.

Comment: The "dpdump" implies data pump.  Is the parallel process using external tables?  Maybe those files have problems?

Comment: @JonHeller, the data pump is not being used at all. That makes the situation very strange. Also, the max open files in linux is set to 65536. About the external_tables used, none of them is using the directory dpdump.

Comment: External tables don't need to refer to the `dpdump` directory (or `DATA_PUMP_DIR`) directly - this seems to be an artefact of the driver. I can see the same thing happening in a quick test. I suspect they stick around until the server process exits - when the DB is shut down. It's probably something to raise a service request for to see if there's a way to avoid or clean them up?

Comment: No solution but just to let you know that we see the exact same problem. I've opened an SR on April 18 2018. But so far there has been no helpful feedback from Oracle on this issue at all.